# Mysql Installation Configuration Stoped at "Starting The Server"

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, failed-installation

I'm Getting This Server Problem For Mysql Installation Every Time I Try To Install Mysql.
I Keep Uninstalling Installing MYSQL But Didn't Find Right Solution.
Hope Some Of You have Answer.
The Logs Says This :- unable to connect mysql:localhost@3306 with user root and no password 
[SS For Ref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olle4.png)

Comment: Can you paste the logs here?

Comment: Waiting until a connection to MySQL Server 8.0.20 can be established (with a maximum of 10 attempts)...
Retry 1: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 5 seconds before the next connection attempt...
Retry 2: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

Comment: Have you set any password to root user? If so that's missing while trying to connect

Comment: While installation we have to set pass for Root else we could not move further,